# Someone explain why is this returning True

Tags: bash, shell-script

Apologies if what I'm asking is stupid. That said, can someone help me out?

```
Pop!_OS based on Ubuntu 21.10 | Linux 5.15.8-76051508-generic | wayland display manager

karthik@cosmic:~$ read -p "enter" VAR
enterANything
karthik@cosmic:~$ echo $VAR
ANything
karthik@cosmic:~$ if [ "$VAR"=="Hello" ]
> then
> echo "True"
> fi
True
karthik@cosmic:~$
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you miss the 'spaces' between `"$VAR"` and `"Hello"`.

In fact,

> if [ "$VAR" == "Hello" ]; then echo "True"; fi

works as should

This is the reason why the statement is broken **but** I am not a Bash expert, I cannot tell you **why** Bash behaves in this way.

*If someone knows, please share it in the comment!*

Comment: Thanks for the quick support. <br>adding spaces make it work! <br>Regarding why bash works that way, I'll google it. <br>Thanks man.

Comment: `[ ... ]`, given a single string between `[` and `]`, returns true if that string is non-empty. It's the same as `[ -n string ]`, and `"$VAR"=="Hello"` is a single non-empty string.